# WP8: SelectedItem is reset when using ListPicker

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, listpicker

In my Windows Phone 8 project I am using a ListPicker control from the SDK Toolkit (v 4.2013.06.11).

In my markup I define the ItemsSource as well as the 2 templates used to render the control:

```
    <toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="StagesList" Margin="24" Grid.Row="2" 
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Model.Stages}"
                        FullModeItemTemplate="{StaticResource stageItemTemplate}"
                        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource stageItemTemplate}">
    </toolkit:ListPicker>
```

In the code-behind I set the DataContext and pre-select the current selection (in OnNavigatedTo) and remember the current selection (in NavigatedFrom):

```
    public SelectOrCreateStage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = App.ViewModel;
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        StagesList.SelectedItem = App.ViewModel.SelectedProduct.Stage;
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
        App.ViewModel.SelectedProduct.Stage = (Stage)StagesList.SelectedItem;
    }
```

The current selection is correctly recorded in the model when OnNavigatedFrom() is executing. After the statement

```
        StagesList.SelectedItem = App.ViewModel.SelectedProduct.Stage;
```

in NavigatedTo is executed (verified in an SelectionChanged event handler) the selection is set correctly. A second SelectionChanged event is raised by the OnApplyTemplate which leaves the SelectedIndex to at the correct value! However, visually

Why is that happening? How can that be avoided? What is the correct way to setup a ListPicker and pre-select an item that is not the first item in the ItemsSource?

Comment: and where do you sign up for the SelectionChanged event handler?

Comment: also is the selected index in the 2nd call -1 by any chanse?